# jquery to refresh div content generated by php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to refresh a div content generated by the same php page using jquery

i have a `test.php`, that contains a div called `refreshdiv`, a button called `refreshbutton` and may other div's that display other contents

the content of `refreshdiv` div is generated by php

is it possible to reload the contents of the `refreshdiv` on clicking `refreshbutton` on the same page ie, `test.php`

here is my work around

```
<div id="refreshdiv">
<table>
 <?php 
   $rec=mysql_query("select * from user_master");
   for($i=0;$i<mysql_fetch_array($rec);$i++) 
   {
 ?>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <?php echo mysql_result($rec,$i,'username');?> 
   </td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

tried using $.get, but didnt get any result

Comment: what's your jquery code look like?

Comment: and did you see anything come back from the server via fiddler, firebug, etc.?

Comment: dont know which jquery function need to use here. as this deals with the portion of the same page.

Comment: basically im newbie in php and jquery...

Comment: Understood.  But what does your javascript/jquery code look like where you're calling `$.get()`?  That's probably the root of the problem.  There's no reason you can't call `$.get()` to refresh portions of the same page -- that's a big use for frameworks like jquery.  Thanks!

Comment: if i call the same page using `$.get()`, will it refresh the entire content. i have other divs that hold some db data.

Comment: No, you can update only the part of the page that you want to refresh with the data returned from `$.get()`.

Comment: i have tried with Boopathi Rajaa code. but its loading entire page in div.

Comment: I put an online example together so you can see what I mean by partial page updates using jQuery's AJAX methods (get, post, etc.).  See my answer below.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/sQRuu/) I put together - it may help.

I'm making an AJAX call (a POST in this case since it's just HTML and that's what jsFiddle supports for HTML requests - but it would be no different for a `$.get` for you) that gets data and appends it to a table data cell (`<td>`).  The whole page doesn't update - just the section that I'm targeting -- in this case, the `<td>` cell, which keeps having "hello's" appended into it.

I hope this helps.  Let me know if you have add'l questions.

Comment: thank you so much for the post. thought there will be something like div.refresh, so that the entire content in the div will loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax

In the test.php use

```
if($_GET['ajax'] == 1) {
  //echo new content;
}
```

and the jQuery code will be

```
function refreshClick() {
  $("#refreshdiv").load("./test.php?ajax=1");
  //OR
  //to customize your call more, you could do
  $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "./test.php?ajax=1",
   success: function(data) { $("#refreshdiv").html(data); },
   error: function(err){ Some_Error_Div.innerHTML = err; }
  });
}
```

Comment: will this affect the other contents in the page. i have other divs that hold data from db.

Comment: this wont affect any other content in that page.... if you hve a few more dependencies then you have to change that separately ... for each div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to set up a php page that will return the contents of the div then access this page via ajax and insert the contents generated by the page into your div. So the jQuery would look something like this -

```
$.ajax({
  url: "div.php",
  success: function(data){
    $('#refreshdiv').html(data);
  }
});
```