# How to refresh PHP code in <DIV> in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem , I want to wirte HTML code that only refreshes the  test , so just the code between de `<div>...</div>`

I was thinking to use some Javascript but I'm not sure this works in PHP , because my in HTML div there's PHP code.

My HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>


</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <div id = "other div">
        <p> text </p> 
    </div>

    <div id="test">

        <?php refresh this code ?>

    </div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You might want to look into AJAX calls: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801001/jquery-to-refresh-div-content-generated-by-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery to refresh div content generated by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801001/jquery-to-refresh-div-content-generated-by-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh only a div in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691435/refresh-only-a-div-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

PHP runs on the server. The only way to rerun it is to make an HTTP request.

There are (essentially) two ways to modify part of a page.

- Use an `iframe` to make part of a page a separate document that can be loaded independently
- Use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM. You can combine this with `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` to retrieve new data over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply